# HTML+CSS | Change Background Location Inside `<div>` - How Can I Achieve This?

Tags: css, image, background, containers, background-image

I have a `<div>` container that I want it to have `height:90vh,width:100vw`.

I want to adjust its position and if there other things needed, them, too, to get from the left picture, to the right picture, inside my container:

[image: Left - before | Right - after]

Is it possible to adjust the position with pixels or something else such that I'd be able to "move" my picture inside my container, but that it'd still wouldn't leave empty space in the container, so it'd fully cover it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You mention you want to get the result on the right side of your image but then say _"wouldn't leave empty space in the container"_ which there is on the right side. By cover do you mean fill? Please clarify (in your post, not comments), thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code, and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to always have the image filling it's container even if the container changes size.

If you haven't already, create another `div` inside the container `div` and set it's `background-image` to your image url ( and remove the `img` ). Then set `background-size: cover;` on the new `div`. Now you can set the container `div` to `display: flex;` and mess with how the new `div` will react to other surrounding content.

E.g.

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(<img_url_here>);"></div>
    <div class="other_varying_height_content"></div>
</div>

CSS:
.container { display: flex; }
.image { background-size: cover; }
```

Note: Your image would suggest you set `background-position: center;` on `.image`